# On topic question closed as duplicate of off-topic question with historical significance

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, historical-lock

I just ran across [What does the 'git add .' ('git add' single dot) command do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16969768/1108305) which is marked as a duplicate of [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/315911/1108305).

The duplicate target was closed as being an off-topic post with historical significance.  It seems pretty self-evident why: it's an unfocused catch-all question on how to use git, which is the opposite of what Stack Overflow questions are supposed to be.

On the other hand, the duplicate question appears to be on topic: it's a focused question about a programming tool.

The off-topic question was locked on May 14, 2012; the duplicate question was closed as a duplicate on Jun 6, 2013.  So the duplicate target was known to be off-topic when the duplicate question was closed.

It feels really off to me that a known off-topic question would be chosen as a duplicate target of something that feels on-topic.

I did a search for other potential duplicate questions, in case it's still a duplicate.  The closest I found is [Difference between "git add -A" and "git add ."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572549/1108305), which while similar, doesn't feel like *quite* the same question.  On the other hand, I'm seriously questioning my search-fu when it comes to duplicates, given the extreme downvoting of a recent meta question of mine ([How does this closed question lack details or clarity?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424484/1108305)) that would have been avoided had I been more successful as duplicate searching.  So I could well be missing something.

Was this closure as a duplicate reasonable when it was done, and something to be emulated?  Or is my intuition correct that this closure shouldn't have happened?

Comment: This is a tough problem because of the historical reluctance to write artificial canonicals and treat the site more as an actual reference library. The model was flawed (although not egregiously so) from the beginning: for a huge fraction of the appropriate question space, people who actually need the good questions answered are especially poorly qualified to devise the right questions.

Comment: I'd say the closure is incorrect simply because (keeping the catch-all question issue aside) there is no answer explaining `git add` or `git add .` in the duplicate target.

Comment: Also, even if the answer _were_...somewhere...in that extremely long guide, it still wouldn't be a duplicate, for many of the same reasons questions that are answered somewhere in the docs are on-topic.  Stack Overflow exists to answer _specific_ questions with _specific_ answers.  Closing as a duplicate of something that requires reading pages and pages of content to find the answer is pretty unhelpful.

Comment: Ugh, nice example. Perhaps it is time to admit that locked questions should not be selectable dupe targets.

Comment: This describes my problem with all omnibus canonicals. When the question is unfocussed garbage, the answer'll be in there and it's probably the best we can do. But when the question is good, closing with the omnibus is a disservice, and basically a big F-you to the asker.

Comment: @user4581301 "When the question is unfocussed garbage, the answer'll be in there and it's probably the best we can do."  In that case, closing as needing more focus feels like it'll lead to a better result.

Comment: Apologies for poor choice of words. As an answer the omnibus is the best we can do. As a close reason it still sucks.